# How to Redirect to the Flutter Web Page URL Direct From the Email?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In my Flutter Web project, I have a Page for reset password and the URL of this page looks like  `https://mypath.com/reset_password/confirm/<uid>/<token>`. the `uid` & `token` are getting added from BE and get added to my URL. When the user clicks on that link it has to redirect to that Flutter page.

## main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  final routeUri = html.window.location.href; // Get the current URL

  // Parse the URL
  final uri = Uri.parse(routeUri);

  String? uid;
  String? token;

  // Check if the URL path matches the "/password_reset/confirm/" route
  if (uri.path == '/password_reset/confirm/') {
    // Extract <uid> and <token> from the path segments
    uid = uri.pathSegments.length > 4 ? uri.pathSegments[4] : null;
    token = uri.pathSegments.length > 5 ? uri.pathSegments[5] : null;
  }

  // Provide default values if uid or token is null
  uid ??= '';
  token ??= '';
  print("UID - $uid TOKEN - $token");
  // http://localhost:8000/account/reset/OQ/15a5fadaa0b0a81cf3c1d7cd64b/

  // envFileName is passed as input env variable in run command
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp(uid, token)));
}
```

The `uid` &  `token` is showing empty.